# Python writerow method for csv

Tags: python, csv

I am using writerow method in python for writing list of values in csv file and it keeps on adding a new line after every row i add. How to stop adding new line ? Below is the chunk of code

```
for exception in tempList:
        statItem = (exception['count'],exception['stack'])
        locStatList.append(statItem)

        sortedStatTempList = sorted(locStatList, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
        writer = csv.writer(open("temp",'w'),quotechar='\x00')
        writer.writerow(["Server Name","JVM","Instance Exception"])

    for exception in sortedStattempList :

        s = str(exception[0])
        p = exception[1]

        tempVar = 'All Tomcat Servers'+','+s+','+p  

        writer.writerow([tempVar])
```

Comment: can you expalain it a little bit more ?

Comment: What is the line where you open the file to write?

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: `writerow` will write row . :) . so it will add new line character to separate two rows .

Comment: writer = csv.writer(open("temp.csv",'w'),quotechar='\x00'), this is the chunk of code that i am using and i need to write a list of values so when i write first row and moves to write second row it inserts a new line and then on the next line it starts writing the data

Comment: Not sure which version of python i am using as i am using it on a unix system

Comment: its after every line i add to the file

Comment: Please provided these details in your question (click `edit`). Add some of the contents of your input file, your code, your current output and your expected output.

Comment: provide code in question not in commnent.

Comment: This is the code that i am using and it gives the output as All Tomcat Servers,SomeVal,SomeVal and then it inserts a new line and then inserts the data, so i want to remove this new line that it adds everytime

Comment: It's importent to know your python version type `import sys print (sys.version)`

Comment: The version that i am using is 2.4.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop Python's csv.DictWriter.writerows from adding empty lines between rows in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361787/how-can-i-stop-pythons-csv-dictwriter-writerows-from-adding-empty-lines-between)

Answer (score 1):

You should open the CSV file using binary mode (read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer)):

```
writer = csv.writer(open("temp",'wb'), quotechar='\x00')
```

Comment: I tried removing the "[]", but then the o/p was something like A,l,l,,T,o,m,c,a,t..... this is not the desired output

Comment: @MatkuJain: Ah yes, I had misread that line. But the suggestion about binary mode still stands...

Comment: Done with the binary mode also but it dint worked

Comment: So there is an empty line between each row of the CSV file?

Comment: Yes there is an empty line between each row and i need to remove that empty file

Comment: Can you look at the file with a hex editor? What exactly is there between lines (`0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A` or `0x0A 0x0A` or...)?

Comment: I dont have any hex editor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file correctly (as Tim suggested), but you can further optimize your code thus:

```
with open('temp','wb') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar='\x00')
  writer.writerow(["Server Name","JVM","Instance Exception"])

  for exception in sortedStattempList:
    tempVar = 'All Tomcat Servers,{},{}'.format(*exception)
    writer.writerow([tempVar])

  # or, you can do this
  lines = ['All Tomcat Servers,{},{}'.format(*e) for e in sortedStattempList]
  writer.writerows(lines)
```

You should avoid concatenating strings, instead use `format` or `join`. The `with statement` will handle closing of the file for you as well.

Comment: I tried the above solution but it dint worked keeps on giving syntax error. and also gave error for tempVar saying "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'"

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: The version that i am using is 2.4.3