# How can I stop Python's csv.DictWriter.writerows from adding empty lines between rows in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, csv

When I use Python's `csv.DictWriter.writerows` on Windows, empty newlines are added between rows. How do I stop that? The code works fine on Linux.

Comment: How are you opening the file to write to?

Comment: Why the `+`; are you reading from it too?

Comment: ah that was leftover from when I was reading while debugging

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- In Python 2: Open the file in binary mode, always; `csv.DictWriter()` writes `\r\n` line endings:

  ```
  with open(filename, 'ab') as outputfile:
      writer = csv.DictWriter(outputfile, fieldnames)
  ```

  From the [`csv.writer()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

  > If *csvfile* is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.
- In Python 3: Open the file with `newline=''` so `csv.DictWriter()` can control the newlines written without translation:

  ```
  with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as outputfile:
      writer = csv.DictWriter(outputfile, fieldnames)
  ```

  Again, quoting the relevant [`csv.writer()` documenation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

  > If *csvfile* is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`
  >
  > [ ... ]
  >
  > If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the csv module does its own (universal) newline handling.