# How can I stop Python's csv.DictWriter.writerows from adding empty lines between rows in Windows when using stdout?

Tags: python, eclipse, csv, python-3.x, pydev

When I run this code in Eclipse using PyDev, I see output with empty lines in between the rows. How can I get rid of them? It happens using python3 only.

```
import csv
import sys

fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=fieldnames)

writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

Output in Eclipse

> first_name,last_name
>
> Baked,Beans
>
> Lovely,Spam
>
> Wonderful,Spam

Output is correct in cygwin-bash, on Linux and incorrect when using redirection to file in cmd.exe + Windows python (Console window is apparently correct)

[image: Output from cmd.exe redirected to file viewed in Notepad++]

Comment: Which app did you use in the screenshot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is pretty clear that the CSV module needs to have control over the newlines; in Python 2 you are expected to open the file object in binary mode, in Python 3, you need  to set the `newline` option to `''`. See [How can I stop Python's csv.DictWriter.writerows from adding empty lines between rows in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361787/how-can-i-stop-pythons-csv-dictwriter-writerows-from-adding-empty-lines-between)

That's because the module writes `\r\n` line separators to the file by default. The windows text mode handling then replaces `\n` with `\r\n` and you see blank lines appear because now lines are separated by `\r\r\n`.

You can set the [`lineterminator` argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) to `'\n'` to change what the module uses to separate lines:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=fieldnames, 
                        lineterminator='\n')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
>>> out = StringIO()
>>> writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=fieldnames)
>>> writer.writeheader()
>>> out.getvalue()
'first_name,last_name\r\n'
>>> out = StringIO()
>>> writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
>>> writer.writeheader()
>>> out.getvalue()
'first_name,last_name\n'
```

`sys.stdout` will still translate that `\n` to `\r\n` but now there is no `\r` preceding it.